# How can I convert the format of columns from multiple data frames?

Tags: r

I have several data frames with some columns sharing the same names. I'm trying to come up a way to change the format of the columns with the same name from different data frames systematically. Here is what I have come up with:

```
data1=data.frame(a=seq(1:10),b=c("a","b"))
data2=data.frame(a=seq(11:20),b=c("c","d"))

temp = c("data1$a","data2$a")

for (i in 1:length(temp)) {
  eval(parse(text=(temp)[i])) = as.character(eval(parse(text=(temp)[i])))
}
```

After running the code, I have got the following message:

```
Error in file(filename, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r") :
  cannot open file 'data1$a': No such file or directory
```

However, if I run the following code, it works:

```
as.character(eval(parse(text=(temp)[1])))
```

Can someone please help to correct my code and explain why it doesn't work?

Comment: Also, regarding the error you're getting with your parse/eval attempt, I don't know exactly what's happening, but it seems to be related to the `*tmp*` artifact of R's implementation of complex lvalues, i.e. lvalues that consist of indexed objects or function calls. I don't know enough about the R internals to be more specific, but that implementation quirk always looked like a hack to me, and this error you're getting looks like an obscure bug in the hack. See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment for some info about `*tmp*`.

Comment: If you run `traceback()` immediately after getting the error, you can see `*tmp*` is doing something fishy. It ends up being passed to `parse()` as an unnamed argument, which is interpreted as a filename that then fails to be opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you're mixing "separateness" and "systematicness" of data handling. In other words, you're trying to store multiple data objects separately in the global environment, but also trying to work with them systematically. I would suggest that this is a mistake. You should choose one approach to data handling, and stick to it.

**1:** Separateness

This one is easy. Just store the data.frames separately (which is exactly what you're doing), and modify them separately:

```
data1 <- data.frame(a=seq(1:10),b=c('a','b'));
data2 <- data.frame(a=seq(11:20),b=c('c','d'));

data1$a <- as.character(data1$a);
data2$a <- as.character(data2$a);
```

**2:** Systematicness

This one requires storing the data in a list from the beginning. That may slightly increase the verbosity of some code, since you have to dereference the list to access the individual data.frames, but it facilitates the systematic data handling that you're looking for, which can eliminate a lot of duplicate code:

```
data <- list(
    data.frame(a=seq(1:10),b=c('a','b')),
    data.frame(a=seq(11:20),b=c('c','d'))
);

for (i in seq_along(data)) data[[i]]$a <- as.character(data[[i]]$a);
```

---

As you can see, each of these approaches alleviates the need to use messy parse/eval solutions. Usually that kind of dynamic code generation, parsing, and evaluation should not be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

We can place the datasets in a `list` (`mget(ls(patterns = "data\\d+"))`), loop over the `list` and convert the column of interest ("col_of_interest") to `character` class.  To reflect the change in the original object, we use `list2env` (but I would recommend to work with `list` instead of individual objects).

```
col_of_interest <- "a"
list2env(lapply(mget(ls(pattern =  "data\\d+")),
      function(x) {x[[col_of_interest]] <- as.character(x[[col_of_interest]])
                  x}), envir = .GlobalEnv)
 str(data1)
 #'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 #$ a: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 #$ b: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
```

NOTE: The idea of placing the datasets in a `list` and converting to `character` for selected columns is already described in this post.

Comment: Hi @akrun, the solution that you have provided works beautifully. I have upvoted your answer but I didn't accept it as the final answer. The reason is that bgoldst's answer is more enlightening as it helps me to understand the difference between Separateness and Systematicness, and this is a more fundamental issue for me. I would like to accept both answers if stackover flow allows that.

Comment: @Cypress Thank you for the note.  It's okay, and yes his answer is more comprehensive and includes the jargons