# Assign a vector dynamically in R

Tags: r, assign

I have multiple vectors *D<sub>i</sub>*, where *i* = 1, 2,..., 40. Now in a *for*-loop, I want to do some operations on these. The following pseudo-code summarizes my objective.

```
for i in 1:40
    D = Di  # How to do this?
    # ... do some operations on D #
```

Edit: Please note that each *Di* is a separate vector.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds silly, but if D is a data frame with i columns, something like `D = D[, i]` should work

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not. Each Di is a separate vector.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple vectors? Do you mean that you have 40 R objects, called D1, D2, D3 etc.? If so, you can use `get(paste0("D", i))` for the loop.

Comment: @Adam, thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @SonuKMishra It would be a good idea to use a list if you are doing a function to all of them, it will allow vectorisation of the process.

Comment: You should look at the answers and consider alternate approach that keeping 40 separate objects in the same environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put them all in a list, each list object (the vector) can be accessed by using the index notation.

```
MyVectors = list(D1 = c(1:10),
                 D2 = c(11:20))

> MyVectors[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> MyVectors[[2]]
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

therefore you can access them as such:

```
for(i in 1:2){
        MyVectors[[i]] =  MyVectors[[i]] + 2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Funnily, [I just answered a similar question about 45 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37246159/how-can-i-convert-the-format-of-columns-from-multiple-data-frames/37246315#37246315). I stand by the philosophy I described in that answer with respect to this question. But because you have 40 loose objects, instead of just 2, the "separateness" approach really doesn't make sense. You should use the "systematicness" approach, as follows:

```
Ds <- list(
    c(...), ## 1st vector
    c(...), ## 2nd vector
    ...
    c(...) ## 40th vector
);

for (i in seq_along(Ds)) {
    ## do some operations on Ds[[i]]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Funnily, I answered another question an hour ago.  In the same way, we can place the `vectors` in a `list` and then do the operation with in each list element

```
 MyVectors = list(D1 = c(1:10),
             D2 = c(11:20))
 lapply(MyVectors, function(x) x +2)
```